# Action bar for phones below API 11

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, navigationbar

I am developing an android app, where I want to put action bar for phones below API 11.
I am following the below link.

http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/

I am making use of the v7 support library, and I am able to get the actionbar. But, the problem is I want to add a navigational listener or tab listener to the action bar. How is it possible.

Please help! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ActionBarSherlock](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Factionbarsherlock.com%2F&ei=c8z4Uq_4OrLo7Ab09IGwBw&usg=AFQjCNEKyOYK1H-iAiI67o4J8dIPJNL9TA&sig2=lghwuwrmpTF1kxaQHQrM3Q&bvm=bv.60983673,d.ZGU).  It is an excellent library of tools that allow you to use Action Bars in older phones and is widely used.  The catch is that all your Activities will need to extend SherlockActivity instead of Activity and you have to be careful to call methods like `getSherlockActivity()` in Fragments instead of `getActivity()`.

Comment: One more Q.. Can I somehow add the sherlock library in the libs folder and use it, instead of referencing it as a seperate project?..I tried exporting it as a jar file and use it .Didnt work so..

Comment: Unfortunately not ... library projects in a jar cannot provide resources for use by the implementing project.  Because of this, and because ActionBarSherlock needs to provide resources, you have to keep it as a project that is referenced by yours.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) library

It allows much more than ActionBarSherlock, but makes your app ~3Mb bigger in size

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have not seen this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html